# Crytal Report not showing arabic when exported to PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I have a web application (ASP.NET with C#.NET as back end). Developed in VS2012 with Crystal Report V13.0.5. Reports are working fine with data in english language. When I have executed reported and converted them to PDF for Arabic language data then it didn't showed me arabic but english or numeric data was on shown on reports. Or when i converted them to to excel file Arabic is shown there as well. I have searched on google but find post which recomend to install arabic font if in linux environment but I am using Windows environment where I have developed application, Arabic is working for all other applications. Only issue is with Crystal Report convert to PDF for Arabic language data.
Anyone can guide me how to fix this issue

[image]

Comment: Adobe does not support some font types regarding Arabic text while excel does because it`s a MS product support Arabic text from the OS itself, try to change the used font type to be Arial Narrow..... after you try it undelete the answer you have deleted earlier!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the crystal report objects font to

> **Arial Unicode MS**

and it works for me